# distance between the radii of two intersecting congruent circles with virtually no info

Tags: geometry, circles

[intersecting circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFVZD.png)

There are two intersecting congruent circles, and I only know the length of the small arcs (coloured in red the image above), is there any way to find out the distance between the radii of the two circles?
Thank you. :)

Comment: Do you know the lengths of the radii?

Comment: Yeah, the length is 2 units

Comment: And what is the length of the red arcs?

Comment: the length is 2π/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Suppose length of the arc is l, radius of circles is r, then $r\theta = l$ where $\theta$ (in radian) is angle subtended by the arc. So $\theta = l/r$. Then the distance between center of the two circles is $2r\cos\dfrac{\theta}{2}$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Just wondering, where is the angle subtended to? Is it the radius? I just realised the question asks for a diagram ヽ(ಠ_ಠ)ノ so what does it look like?

Comment: The value you provided $l = 2\pi/3$ ; $r=2$, so $\theta = \pi/3$.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm still not sure - is  the angle between the intersection or the one next to it?

Comment: @Sophie  I just added a picture in my answer, to explain.

Comment: Thanks so much ヾ(＾-＾)ノ

Comment: Glad that it helped, in that case you may consider clicking the tic mark in the answer , to mark it correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

@amitava gave you the correct answer, for the general case of any , r and . In this specific case, since  is 60° [/360°=2/3/4], we can solve it using basic geometry, without trigonometric functions.

All the radii are equal, so if you connect the centers with the endpoints of the arc, you get a rhombus. In a rhombus, the diagonals bisect the, bisect each other, and are perpendicular to each other.

So if you draw the diagonals, you get a 30-60-90 right triangle where the long leg is half of the distance between  the centers, and the long leg in a 30-60-90 triangle is √3/2 times the hypotenuse.
[image: overlapping circles with rhombus]

You can see a detailed step-by-step proof here:https://geometryhelp.net/distance-between-centers-overlapping-congruent-circles/